# How to store microsecond level timestamps in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to store data in cassandra which contains microsecond level timestamps.
Cassandra's docs say that the 'timestamp' data type can store milliseconds since epoch but several messages on the internet seem to imply that cassandra can natively store microsecond timestamps.

What is the best way practice for storing microsecond level times in cassandra? Should I just leave out the date part and store a long?

I'm trying to sore a columsn which look like this:
2015-11-18 07:30:46.700824

I get the following error:

ErrorMessage code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unable to coerce '2015-11-18 07:30:18.261543' to a  formatted date (long)"

Aborting import at record #1. Previously inserted records are still present, and some records after that may be present as well.

My cassandra version:
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.11 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]

EDIT:
Here is an example of microsecond confusion in Cassandra's own docs:

"CAS and new features in CQL such as DROP COLUMN assume that cell timestamps are microseconds-since-epoch"

https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeChangesC_c.html

Another: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8297

EDIT2:
I should mention that I intend to query this using spark. From what I understand, spark parses its own flavor of sql and translates it to cassandra (although I'm using CassandraContext in zeppelin). Anything which might help or hinder my search for microsecond level timestmaps?

Comment: There are two different concepts here: storing a timestamp in a 'column' and the timestamp "tag" that Cassandra uses internally (essentially for node synchronization and insert/upsert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bigint or a timeuuid. Type 1 uuid's have 100ns precision so it can cover you. Some utilities, libraries, convenience functions may not give you what you need though so be prepared to write some uuid functions.

Comment: Interesting. Are timeuuids required to be unique across rows? Because in my data, they may not be.

Comment: "Are timeuuids required to be unique across rows?" - No, If I understand your question correctly.  If using it as the partition key, or row key with the data being in the same partition it will. If you need it unique generally you can use the sub-precision part of the time to provide uniqueness. It also includes the mac address (or ip address + jvm static random number, depending on implementation) of the server generating it which provides additional. Although you would be limited to 10 uniques per microsecond per server that way.

Comment: What I mean is that with the amount of data I have, there are bound to be _many_ instances where multiple entries have the same timestamp. "UUID" is specifically supposed to be for unique identifiers (not specific to cassandra). Wondering if I'm signing up for surprises later on if I use timeuuid to store my time data.

Comment: type 1 timeuuid is essentially a 100ns precision timestamp + a unique "node" identifier (usually mac address). Just have to keep that in mind when designing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28MAC_address_.26_date-time.29